# Sort 40k images in a folder python

Tags: python, sorting, operating-system, python-imaging-library, glob

```
import os
import time
from PIL import Image as PImage
import pathlib 
import glob

try:
    path = r"\\x.x.x.x\PVCTData\ELImages\2021_03_08"
    os.chdir(path)
    combo = os.listdir(path)
    combo.sort(key=os.path.getctime,reverse=True)
    print("done")
    print(combo)
    x=0
    loadedimages=[]
 
    for image in combo:
            print(image)
            img = PImage.open(os.path.join(path,image))
            loadedimages.append(img)
            x+=1
            if x>3:
                break
    print(loadedimages)
    loadedimages[0].show()
    loadedimages[1].show()
    loadedimages[2].show()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Assuming i have a shared folder with 40k pictures. I would like to sort the pictures based on the creation date as my machine will send new picture to the folder every 5 seconds. The code above can work but it is too slow to handle the amount of pictures which it took about 15 mins in order to sort and show. I only need to show the latest 60 pictures every 1 hour.

Comment: do you have any chances to change the workflow such that new image land in a new folder and are put into some sort of archive when they are older? Working like this is really not efficient. The archive should also be subdivided because having a  massive amount of files in one folder isn't good practice either.

Comment: hi, i dont have the right to change the workflow as it already implemented by the vendor themselves. What can i do now is to write a program to extract from the shared folder given

Comment: then you should try to do that, sort everything and move all older files to some archive/other dir. This way you get rid of the workload for the sorting algorithm which should be the weak link here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the file list before sorting, such that any file you don't care about is not sorted. I recommend you move the files you don't need to another location (organized properly is a plus).

To do so use something like this before sorting:

```
combo = os.listdir()
currentTime = time.time()
timerange = 310
oldestOK = currentTime - timerange
filtered = list()
for file in os.listdir():
    if path.getctime(file) > oldestOK:
        filtered.append(file)

filtered.sort(key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
```

Comment: this is clean and very clear. Thnks Christian

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to use the last 60 items, why not just only loop over that part of the sort?
So instead of

```py
for image in combo:
```

```py
for image in combo[:60]:
```

Of course I'm not sure which part takes longer (the sorting, or handling the images after they are sorted).
And ofcourse what Christian  stated, try to order them in more subdirectories after you've managed them.

Comment: thank you for ur response. Is the last 60 items will always be the newest?

Comment: This is not working as i cannot sort the last 60 items by using combo[:60]

Comment: My suggestion will help after the sorting.. My question was, where is it actually stuck the longest, in the sorting part, or loading all the images in the PIL library.
If you let python sort it first and afterwards only loop over the first 60-items it will improve you performance, since it will matter if you load 40k images into pill, or 60.
If the sorting of the files is already slow, your best bet is Christian's suggestion.

Comment: Load images is fine. Sorting part took about 12 mins. Is the last item in the list directory when using os.listdir(path) always shows the file that newly created?

Comment: Ok, so apparently we need to try to reduce the list we're going to execute the operation on.  
One could maybe write a file with files already processed and just skip those from sorting?  
Maybe you could use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (search for st_mtime), to check the creation time before handling it, since you get a timestamp you could compare.  
Also have you tested how long python even takes to only loop over said list? If it takes 12 minutes to print all files, don't think you'll be able to make it perform as you would like...